# How to convert our programs to good end product?

Tags: project-planning

What should be the steps followed for writing a successful projects.

I could write programs but fail to convert it into a good end product. I know coding is a very small part in creating a successful  project, I would like to upgrade myself for it ?

Thanks for any suggestions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make it easy for the customers to use
2. Find a good marketing team
3. Listen to Customers and start making changes based on their feed back
4. Take care of your customers so that they recommend your porduct to others

Answer (score 1):

Create something that people need. Something that they would gladly use. Something that is better than what's available now. That will take care of the rest.

A project turns into a product when it has customers. So approach it from this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the otherway around.
First find a customer then wants to pay for a project, make what they want. Then when it can be used by more customers make it a product.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is going to drive you forward is to find something that interests *you* first and foremost.

Are you interested in graphics?
Are you interested in games?
Do you have a itch to scratch in the area of productivity tools?
Are you consumed by Twitter?

Whatever it is, you'll probably find there are a lot of other folks interested in that too.  I think you'll find that if you can focus on something that you are passionate about that has some sort of applicability in the lives of others, **and** you can take it from concept to a finished, application, there will be a market there.

But whatever you write has to be darn good to get anyone to pay for it because there are a world of free and open source apps out there already.  If I am your target market, you'd better wow me if you expect me to fork over my hard-earned greenbacks for your application.

You probably already know whether you can market things yourself, and I'd guess that you aren't a marketing person.  No slight intended against you - I'm not one either.  If you were, you would have phrased your question differently or not asked it at all.  As others have posted, you'll need a good marketing machine to get your app noticed.  There are lots of innovative ways to get your app noticed and depending on the platform, there are some easy ways to handle the business side (e.g., the iPhone app store).

If it were me, I'd focus on developing something that is of high quality and give a "lite" version of it away... let the end user try it out and see if it has a market.  I've purchased a TON of apps from the iPhone app store by trying the "lite" version first and then forking over my money for the full version.

Focus on quality and the market will be there, I bet.

Just my two cents.